# Crate DB - Exporting tables to different S3 endpoint with COPY TO command

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cratedb

I have a need to export a Crate DB table to S3, I can do this with COPY TO command by providing s3 endpoint. But I need this to be exported to a different S3 endpoint and not default AWS S3 endpoint.
How to provide the alternate s3 endpoint and credentials?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible.

You can request this feature by creating an issue on the [crate github](https://github.com/crate/crate) repository.